# i am in same network but unable to share resources through mobie

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, metasploit

my laptop is in 192.168.1.6 and mobile in 192.168.1.3 , turned on xampp or apache 2 . when i tried to access  files from laptop /var/www/html through mobile with ip 192.168.1.3 . it shows not reachable .

I tried in my friend network with 192.168.0.x series and sharing is working through mobile

Comment: Maybe some firewall on the server side? Are you sure your netmask is properly configured?

Comment: Problem solved , just reset my router and problem got solved